# What's wrong with this get method call using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape a web page. When executing this code, it outputs `running1` but not `running2`. Why would this be the case?

Code:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

print("running1")

url = "https://www.johnlewis.com/nordictrack-commercial-14-9-elliptical-cross-trainer/p5639979"
response = requests.get(url)

print("running2")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

print("running3")
```

Comment: hmm, looks like the only import you're actually using is for `requests`. I'd probably remove one for bs4 unless you actually use it here.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I've included more code; I'm also using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: the `bs4` import is redundant if you're saying that you basically don't get past the second `print` statmeent. I just don't see the point of it in this specific issue you were noticing.

Comment: They're intentionally stalling your request because you don't have a User-Agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get correct response from server try to specify `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0"
}

url = "https://www.johnlewis.com/nordictrack-commercial-14-9-elliptical-cross-trainer/p5639979"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Prints:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>

...
```